# Subcaption package (problem with \vfill)

Tags: subfloats

I have 5 subfigures and I can't make \vfill work. All the figures are together and the result is not what I expect. Here is the code I used:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6 cm,height=5 cm]{P101}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6 cm,height=5 cm]{p102}
\end{subfigure} 

\vfill

\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6 cm,height=5 cm]{p103}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=6 cm,height=5 cm]{p104}
\end{subfigure}

\vfill

\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{PBG}
\end{subfigure}
\caption{Interacciones en la ALA-D.}
\end{figure}
```

The output I get is the following image: 
[image]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\vfill` would work if you have defined height of `figure` float. Since it is determined by images height, it hasn't desired effect. Instead of it you should use some other command, for example `\vspace{<amount>}` or  predefined `\medskip` etc.

I wonder, why you use environment `subfigure` if you not use sub captions for them. With them your figure will appear as:

[image]

if you not need sub captions, than you put images simple in tabular environments. Code for the first case is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{showframe}% only for show page layout

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5 cm]{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5 cm]{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5 cm]{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
    \hfil
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth,height=5 cm]{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}

\medskip
\begin{subfigure}{0.45\textwidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image}
\caption{}
\end{subfigure}
    \caption{Interacciones en la ALA-D.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:**
And before forgotten uploaded case of use simple tabular environment:

[image]

which have shorter MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htb]
    \centering
    \begin{tabular}{cc}
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5 cm]{example-image}
    &    \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5 cm]{example-image}  \\[1ex]
\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5 cm]{example-image}
    &    \includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5 cm]{example-image}  \\[1ex]
\multicolumn{2}{c}{\includegraphics[width=5cm,height=5 cm]{example-image}}
    \end{tabular}

    \caption{Interacciones en la ALA-D.}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked :) I don't need subcaptions in this case. Is there a simpler way to get the desired effect?

Comment: yes, see my edit, before I forgot to upload second case without them